# How to prevent BFGS from getting stuck on astronomically large gradient?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, newton-method, quasi-newton, numerics

I have implemented BFGS myself from scratch in order to solve minimization problems.  Part of BFGS, as I understand it, is that the approximation to the Hessian is supposed to be positive definite, which means it is supposed to be invertible.   I have been following the algorithm outlined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm#Algorithm .  This is how we update our approximation to the Hessian:

$$ B_{k+1} = B_k + \frac{ y_k y_k ^T }{y_k^T s_k} – \frac{ B_k s_k s_k^T B_k}{s_k^T B_k s_k} $$

where 
$ y_k = \nabla f(x_k) - \nabla f(x_{k-1}) $ and

$s_k = -1 * B_k^{-1} \nabla f (x_k)$

I made a few slight modifications to the standard BFGS algorithm in my implementation:

1)  I check to see if $y_k^T s_k$ is negative.  If it is, then this has the potential to make the next update $B_k$ negative, too.  So, I switch to an alternative update when that term is negative:

$$ B_{k+1} = B_k + \frac{ y_k y_k ^T }{y_k^T y_k} – \frac{ B_k s_k s_k^T B_k}{s_k^T B_k s_k} $$
2)  I have a check for when the direction it is about to step $d_k$ might be too large or too small compared to the magnitude of the gradient:  if either $||d_k|| \ge 100*||\nabla f|| $ or $||\nabla f^T * d_k|| \le 10^{-4} * ||\nabla f||*||d_k||$.  If either one of those are true, then I just use the gradient step, $d_k = \nabla f $.

Now I am running into an issue where the gradient somehow becomes very large:  $\nabla f$ becomes very large.  So, when I go to update $s_k$, it becomes very large:  $s_k = -1 * B_k^{-1} \nabla f$.  Then, this causes the next iterate of $B_k$ to be very large.  Eventually, the matrix becomes so large that `np.linalg.inv(B_k)` throws an error and will not be inverted.

How do I protect against this happening?  Do I need another check, and why isn’t my existing preventative measure working for this?

Comment: You haven't told us anything about your particular function and its gradient.  A standard trick in the BFGS method whenever you get into numerical trouble is to restart the method with $B=I$ and a gradient descent step.

Comment: I will try that, thanks.  I'm assuming that "numerical trouble" here should just be defined as whenever the matrix $B_k$ is not invertible - for any reason.  Do we care about the reason *why* the matrix is not invertible?  Or should I just reset to the identity and steepest descent (gradient step), regardless?

Comment: Also, is my approach for checking if $y_k^T s_k \lt 0$ valid?

Comment: Once $B_{k}$ is nearly singular, you get crazy search directions.  Thus it''s wise to restart the method with a steepest descent step as soon as $B_{k}$ becomes nearly singular.

Comment: I tried setting a catch for when $B_k$ has a really high condition number.  It doesn’t help. I tried resetting $B_k$ to the identity, and setting $d_k$ to the gradient $\nabla f$ (and I also tried setting it to $\nabla f / ||\nabla f ||$.  But, the gradient $g_k$ keeps growing astronomically,  and even though I reset $B_k$ to the identity, $g_k$ eventually gets so large that it causes $B_k$ to become too large for numpy to handle, even in just one multiplication.

Comment: Given you are not sharing the objective function, some trivial suggestions: 1) is the gradient computed correctly? 2) have you tried with finite differences? 3) Does the update matrix get singular (look at the eigenvalues...)?

Comment: There is a chance that for your problem the Hessian is ill conditioned or is nearly singular. In such cases, you will get huge Newton steps. Try to put your BFGS algorithm within a trust-region framework. Refer, Nocedal and Wright or if possible the book Trust region methods by Conn et al.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far guys.  Assuming I’ve implemented the objective function correctly (I’ve checked it).  Yes, of course the matrix becomes ill-conditioned.   But the root of the problem is that I cannot find a step size that does not result in $s_k$ being superlarge.  And, that causes $ s_k ^T*y_k$ to also be large, so if there is a single negative component to it, then of course that drives it to be even more negative, and keeps $H_k$ to be ill-conditioned. Any other hints on how to debug this?  Or on how to choose a step size to help avoid an enormous gradient? (I’m using weak wolf)

Comment: @Hunle Did you look into trust-region methods? You need to "dampen" the Newton step with a trust-region.